# mirroring on sql server 2012 on different windows server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-connection, windows-server-2008, database-mirroring

I have 2 servers *.203 and *.205

I have sql server 2012 on each of them

I tried to make mirroring between them every thing goes successfuly but when I tried to start mirroring it gives me exception

(Msg 1418, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

The server network address "TCP://172.16.1.203:5023" can not be reached or does not exist. Check the network address name and that the ports for the local and remote endpoints are operational.)

Comment: And what is the question? Can zou trz some basseline debugging? And remember stackoverflow is for programming, not "help me adminsitrate my server"?

Comment: Your previous question was **already** migrated to dba.stackexchange.com - please: this site is for **programming-related** Q&A - if you have DBA-related stuff, **please** next time ask it on dba.stackexchange.com !